# ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use when attempting to start a Salesforce Function

Tags: salesforce-functions

I am seeing this error in terminal when trying to start a function:

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Functions, by default, uses port 8080 to run locally. It is likely that port 8080 is being used by a different process already when attempting to start your function. To resolve this interference and forcefully kill the process currently using port 8080, open up `cmd` and execute:

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :8080') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %P /T /F
```